# How to create a Lazy property passing a string property of <this> class as parameter to it in C#?

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

Is there a way to pass the Name property as paramter to the Lazy BOM Initialization?

```
public class Item
{
    private Lazy<BOM> _BOM = new Lazy<BOM>(); // How to pass the Name as parameter ???

    public Item(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;         
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public BOM BOM { get { return _BOM.Value; } }
}

public class BOM
{
    public BOM (string name)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [factory overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642329(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Lazy<T>` to achieve this. This also means that the instantiation must, as Zohar's comment suggests, be moved to the constructor, as non static fields cannot be referenced from field initializers.

```
public class Item
{
    private Lazy<BOM> _BOM;

    public Item(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        _BOM = new Lazy<BOM>(() => new BOM(Name));
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public BOM BOM { get { return _BOM.Value; } }
}

public class BOM
{
    public BOM(string name)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn! too fast by half a minute! :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've had too much coffee

Comment: I haven't had enough :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of instantiating the `Lazy<BOM>` at declaration, instantiate it in the constructor of `Item`:

```
public class Item
{
    private Lazy<BOM> _BOM;

    public Item(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;  
        _BOM = new Lazy<BOM>(() => new BOM(name));
    }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public BOM BOM { get { return _BOM.Value; } }
}
```